# jQuery textscaling from middle?

Tags: jquery, animation, text, scale

I have created an simple textanimation here: http://jsbin.com/odivor/16/edit
My problem now is that the text (büro exit) is scaling from left and not from the middle. How could I fix this?

I don´t want to use the jQuery Ui scale.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this :

http://jsbin.com/odivor/23

Your `h2` need a big size to expand unhindered. You may have to tweak the `left` value according to the exact position you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your h2 style to

```
header h2
{
  position: absolute;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: -18px auto 0px auto;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 7.3em;
  text-align: center;  
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```